# Why does the features in my Ubuntu stop working one by one?

Tags: 16.04

I have noticed that some features in my Ubuntu 16.04 (in Thinkpad E470) stopped functioning. It's also a gradual process (I mean more such things keep showing up).

1. Terminal doesn't open through Ctrl + Alt + T.
2. Nearby wifi networks not getting listed. Sometimes I get internet (through auto-connect to some previous network), but I can't see which network I am connected to! etc.

How can I do a diagnosis of my system (to check if the OS or some other application is broken etc.)

**Updates**

*26-Jul-2019: Booting in recovery mode. (As required by @heynnema)*

1. In grub -> advanced options, I have five options for booting in the recovery mode. I chose the first one.
   [image: as shown in this image below]
2. fsck command fails, showing '/dev/sda7 is mounted, e2fsck cannot continue, aborting).
   [image: filesystem mounted error.]

*27-Jul-2019: Answer to the question (on listing the nearby networks) by @heynnema*

It doesn't happen always (the network listing part). Now I can see the WiFi networks in the UI also. Still pasting the results.

`$ iwlist wlp5s0 scan
wlp5s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: C8:D7:19:99:8B:82
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm

                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"CADSL"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001357635dc9
                    Extra: Last beacon: 94184ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0005434144534C
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A7C181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: Unknown: DD760050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700104CFBAA57F4EB9719A19BF929BB1B0203102100074C696E6B7379731023000545313230301024000776322E302E30331042000234321054000800060050F2040001101100054531323030100800022688103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180201F02C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00`

Comment: Start with running "advanced " boot option ( assuming you running grub) - recovery mode. Sometime that works - most of the time gets you into "emergency mode" which is hit and miss.

Comment: @heynnema Updated in the question. Please check. Sorry for the delay

Comment: Follow the process for 18.04 and then fsck will work.

Comment: Okay. I don't have a live CD/ pendrive now. Will do it and post the results. Is there an alternative without a live CD/USB?

Comment: @dtypist no, you must use a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB for your version.

Comment: FYI: re: "Terminal doesn't open through Ctrl + Alt + Tab"... it's ctrl+alt+t

Comment: FYI: re: "Nearby wifi networks not getting listed". Edit your question and show me `iwlist wlan0 scan`... changing wlan0 to your device name.

Comment: Lets first check your file system for errors. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the `/dev/XXXX` device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX`, replacing `XXXX` with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results.